# Specify the kind of measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $ \Omega $ be a set. Consider the $ \sigma $-Alegbra $$ \mathcal{A}:=\{A\subseteq \Omega: A \text{ is countable or } A^c \text{ is countable}\}. $$

I try to classify these kind of measurable functions $ f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R} $.

So let $ a,b\in \mathbb{R} $ be arbitrary. Because $ f $ is measurable it follows
$$ A_{a,b}:=f^{-1}([a,b])=\{x\in \Omega: a\leq f(x)\leq b\}\in \mathcal{A}. $$

So this means $A_{a,b}$ or $(A_{a,b})^c$ is countable.

So it holds especially for $a=b$ which means $A_{a,a}=\{x\in \Omega: f(x)=a\}\in \mathcal{A} $ which means $ f $ is constant on a countable set.

Now I want to show that it doesn't hold if $a\neq b$ which means $A_{a,b}$ and $(A_{a,b})^c$ are not countable, so $A_{a,b}\notin \mathcal{A}$.

Let assume there exist $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $ a\neq b $ such that $A_{a,b}$ and $(A_{a,b})^c$ are not countable.

From here I get stuck because I have no idea to strive for a contradiction.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is countable every function is measurable...

Comment: Is that because $A_{a,b}\in \{\{\}, A, \Omega\}\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ with $ A\subseteq \Omega $?

Comment: And how shall I proceed if $ \Omega $ is uncountable?